# How to get a character in a matrix using uitable

Tags: matlab, uitableview

I'm creating a function that lets an user add or remove his/her input to the list. In this case, uitable. (Matlab)
In fact, the following code was a draft and just thinking about ideas.
Does anybody know a similar example?

(edit_com : add, delete_com : remove)

```
% to add an input to a list
function edit_com_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
value = get(handles.insert_com, 'String'); %user input (char)
data = get(handles.uitable1, 'Data') % read table matrix
data(end+1,:) = 0; %  add below the data matrix sequently. 
% this is for test and I want to put an char input instead of numbers.
set(handles.uitable1, 'Data',data); 

% cell selection function before a delete function
function uitable1_CellSelectionCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % no selection
if ( numel(eventdata.Indices) == 0 )
% only one selected
elseif ( numel(eventdata.Indices) == 1 )
set(handles.delete_com, 'Enable', 'on'); % "delete" buttion activate
selected_com = eventdata.Indices(1); % read currently selected row
set(handles.edit_com, 'UserData', selected_com);
        % more than 2 selected
else
set(handles.delete_come, 'Enable', 'on'); % "delete" buttion activate
selected_com = eventdata.Indices(:,1); % read currently selected rows
set(handles.edit_com, 'UserData', selected_com); 
end

% deletion part
function delete_com_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if get(handles.edit_com, 'UserData') ==0   % none selected
 else if get(handles.edit_com, 'UserData') ==1   % one selected
 data = get(handles.uitable1, 'Data') % 
  data(row_1,:)=[]; % delete
else  % more than one selected
data = get(handles.uitable1, 'Data')
  data(row_2,:)=[]; % delete them
end
```

first it separates several cells from the cell and then separates them (separated by user data). I'm just trying to figure out which column is selected, and I try to erase it from a function. It's hard to deal with it
because it consists of characters and I don't know how to handle cells. What's the best way to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use strings (character arrays) inside pass to your `uitable` a `Data` parameter being of type `cell`, for example;

```
data = cell(10,10); % a 10-by-10 empty cell matrix
set(handles.uitable1,'Data',data);
```

or:

```
data = repmat({'hi'},10,10); % a 10-by-10 matrix of cells containing the string "hi"
set(handles.uitable1,'Data',data);
```

For what concerns the main function:

```
% Here you should disable your delete button when nothing is selected,
% and enable it back when something is selected. Your indices data should
% always be kept up-to-date. You don't need to handle too many cases,
% "something selected" and "nothing selected" is enough.

function uitable1_CellSelectionCallback(hObject,eventdata,handles)
    if (isempty(eventdata.Indices))
        set(handles.delete_com,'Enable','off');
        rows = [];
    else
        set(handles.delete_com,'Enable','on');
        rows = eventdata.Indices(:,1);
    end

    set(handles.edit_com,'UserData',rows);
end
```

Now, for what concerns the addition of rows:

```
function edit_com_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    value = get(handles.insert_com,'String');

    data = get(handles.uitable1,'Data');
    data(end+1,:) = {value};

    set(handles.uitable1,'Data',data);
end
```

And for what concerns the removal of rows:

```
function delete_com_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    data = get(handles.uitable1,'Data');
    rows = get(handles.edit_com,'UserData');

    idx = (1:size(data,1))';
    idx(rows) = [];
    data = data(idx,:);

    set(handles.uitable1,'Data',data);
end
```